# How to use a swift module in an objective-c module with SwiftPM?

Tags: objective-c, swift, llvm, swift-package-manager

Here is an example of the root directory

```
├── Package.swift
└── Sources
    ├── Objc-cli
    │   └── main.m
    └── Swifty
        └── MyStruct.swift
```

Where the `Swifty` module is just a simple struct

```
// MyStruct.swift

public struct MyStruct {
    public var text = "Hello, World!"

    public init() {
    }
}
```

And in the `Objc-cli` I try to link the swift module like this.

```
// main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import Swifty <---- Not found

int main() {
    NSLog(@"Hello from Objc");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the `Package.swift` looks like:

```
// Package.swift

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyTest",
    targets: [
        Target(name: "Swifty", dependencies: []),
        Target(name: "Objc-cli", dependencies: ["Swifty"]),
    ]
)
```

Sadly the compiler doesn't recognise the `Swifty` module inside the objective-c module. Here is the output:

```
$ swift build
Compile Swift Module 'Swifty' (1 sources)
Compile Objc-cli main.m
/tmp/TestPackage/Sources/Objc-cli/main.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'Swifty' not found
@import Swifty
 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
1 error generated.
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
```

Have I missed something or is it simply impossible for now ?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `@import Swifty`?

Comment: @masters3d  What i'm trying is to import a swift module into an objective-c module. What's the purpose of removing the import ?

Comment: If the obj-c module is a Test package inside a swift package, you do not need the import.

Comment: @masters3d objc tests seems not supported by SPM. I get this:
test is not yet supported.: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftpm/swiftpm-11750/Sources/Build/Command.link(ClangModule).swift, line 48
[1]    47975 illegal hardware instruction  swift test

Have you another suggestions ?

Comment: It's coming in a new version. https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to import Swift module in C module, it only works another way around, import C into Swift.

You can find detailed information at SwiftPM - [C language targets](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#c-language-targets)

Comment: the link is 404ing, base page here: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/master/Documentation

Comment: Updated the link, here it is https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#c-language-targets